# PHP: strip html+php from message

Tags: php

Yes i am having an normal output from the database of a message, with this:

```
echo nl2br($show["status"]);
```

I am in a huge risk, as you can use html, e.g if you write `<h1>HAHA</h1>` it turns out in html. if i do `<?php echo "HAHA"; ?>` nothing gets output, so i think it runs the echo. How can i be most safe, and strip everything a user would try to do, html, php and so on..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entering `<?php echo "HAHA"; ?>` doesn't *appear* to do anything. If your right-click to "view-source" of the page the source you will see it is just output as plain text which the browser hides.

Also, you are setup for a CSFR attack by not escaping your output. Instead use [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) and [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags).

```
print nl2br(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($show["status"]), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'));
```

Also, strip_tags **isn't enough on it's own!** as it doesn't validate *BAD HTML*.

Comment: Ah, PHP. Awesome name (`nl2br`). Thanks for being descriptive about that the function does!

Answer (score 3):

i think you'r looking for the function htmlspecialchars(); which masks all html entities in a string.

see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

Use strip_tags.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to try a few different things, but you can do mysql_real_escape_string to start

Comment: This is for preparing text to be inserted into a database; @Johnson is interested in cleaning up output to the browser (if I understood correctly).  Good tool for keeping your database safe, though.

Comment: Ahh I see... I guess I read the question wrong. Oh well... still good to use under different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

[strip_tags()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will remove HTML.  PHP isn't an issue; if you output it to a browser, is's just text and not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out strip_tags: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
$noHtmlString = strip_tags($text);
```

Strings stored in the database that contain `<?php echo "HAHA"; ?>` won't be processed by PHP so should be safe anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think strip_tags will meet your needs.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php